# Why am I getting Too many re-renders in my code and how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and Javascript, and I've occurred this problem, I don't know why it acts like that, but I think I know that my function is rendering too many times by setting the State for `setEpisodeList` over and over again I guess, how do I resolve this in my code?

The `info` state contains an `episodes` object that has an array type.

I have over 1000 episodes in 1 array, so I want to split that 1 big `episodes` array that contains over 1000 episodes into smaller chunks, each chunk will be an array that contains 10 episodes in it, that's why I'm using `episodeListChunk.push(info.episodes.splice(0, 10))`.

So it'll become

```
[ 
 [chunk 1 - 10 episodes], 
 [chunk 2 - 10 episodes], 
 [chunk 3 - 10 episodes], 
 [chunk 4 - 10 episodes], ... 
]
```

If I use `console.log(episodeListChunk)`, I see it's working fine.

[image: What I want]

But if I'm `setEpisodeList(episodeListChunk)` then I get too many re-renders. Does that mean every time the while loop runs it'll setState every time? If that's so, which approach should I be doing to handle these situations?

Here's my code:

```
function MovieWatch({ instance }) {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
    const [episodeList, setEpisodeList] = useState([])

    let { slug } = useParams()

    const getInfo = async () => {
        const { data } = await instance.get("/getInfo?slug=" + slug)
        setInfo(data.data)
        setDone(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInfo()
    }, [])

    const chunkEpisode = () => {
        const episodeListChunk = []
        while (info.episodes.length) {
            episodeListChunk.push(info.episodes.splice(0, 10))
        }
        setEpisodeList(episodeListChunk)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>Hello info page</div>
            {!done ? (
                <Loading loading={true} background="#000000" loaderColor="#FFFF00" />
            ) : (
                <>
                    {info ? chunkEpisode() : console.log("")}
                    <div>Done loading</div>
                </>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you fetch just a chunk of your episodes, don't fetch them all. That's a better approach I guess.

Comment: @merko, thanks for giving me some other ways, but is there really no way to do it in the front-end? I saw someone doing it and I just want to give it a try. Something like this: https://imgur.com/vnwnRFE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the above answers, I've tried to instead of creating 1 big array at first, then I just splice it whenever the first time I receive that big array, I don't know if my explanation is correct or not...

From what @Rejo Mathew ways of using `chunkEpisode(data.data)`, then I wonders what's the point of setting `info` state, so I removed it, and from @Steve K with @MWO explained, I tried to do this. It's working fine now.

But still, I still do not want to do it this way, seems odd to me than the first one, because the first one seems cool to me, weird why it's not working.

Instead of `setInfo`, then use that `info` to implement into the function, I just use that data I received from without setting it, then merge the `chunkEpisode` into `getInfo` function, then use `useEffect` to just only call it once I guess.

Here's the code after I do it:

```
function MovieWatch({ instance }) {
    const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
    const [episodeList, setEpisodeList] = useState([])

    let { slug } = useParams()

    const getInfo = async () => {
        const { data } = await instance.get("/getInfo?slug=" + slug)

        const episodeListChunk = []
        while (data.data.episodes.length) {
            episodeListChunk.push(data.data.episodes.splice(0, 10))
        }
        setEpisodeList(episodeListChunk)
        setDone(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInfo()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div>Hello info page</div>
            {!done ? (
                <Loading loading={true} background="#000000" loaderColor="#FFFF00" />
            ) : (
                <>
                    {console.log(episodeList)}
                    <div>Done loading</div>
                </>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

The result after I changed my code this way.

[image: Worked]

But please give me more advice to optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting info when the component is rendered. Then you are checking if the info is set and running the chunkEpisodes function. `{info ? chunkEpisode() : console.log("")}`. Info will be set every time so you are constantly running the chunkEpisodes function. Instead of running this check you should put it in a useEffect hook with info as a dependency and if info is set then run the chunkEpisodes function. Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(info){
    chunkEpisode()
  }
}, [info])
```

Comment: why would info be set every time?

Comment: Because you run getInfo when the component is first mounted. Then it sets the info and re-renders the component. After that the info will be set so you run your check to see if the info is set and it runs the chunkEpisode function. Which sets the episode list and re-renders the component. Then your check runs again and see's the info is set and runs the chunkEpisode function again and again.

Comment: i see info being set only once, and chunkEpisode() runs every time because info is still set and state episodeList has changed -  but probably we mean the same

Comment: If I do this then it can't read the `info.episodes.length` and I get `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`, leading to `indicates a memory leak`, and yes like @MWO said, I think the `info` only run once

Comment: The info is only running once and is set once. But every time you call a `setState()` the component re-renders. So your info will be set at this point. Then you check if the info is set and call the  `chunkEpisode()` function and call the `setState()` function for that re-rendering the component. Then your component re-renders and checks if the info is set. It is and you call the `chunkEpisode()` functon again and again. As for the memory leak are you navigating away from this component? This happens when you are trying to set the state of a component that is no longer available.

Comment: @SteveK Thanks Steve, from your explanation, I get what you mean, but even I use `useEffect` to call `chunkEpisode()` only whenever the `info` is changing, I get `indicates a memory leak` and it can't read the `length` due to `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In React, every time any state changes the whole component gets re-rendered.

When this happens React will go through JSX and try to detect changes to any state and re-render them.

Since, you have invoked `chunkEpisode()` in JSX, it is causing state change i.e `episodeList`. Because of state change, the JSX is re-renderd, invoking `chunkEpisode()` again. This is happening infinitely.

A better approach would be to invoke `chunkEpisode()` using `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (info) {
      chunkEpisode()
    }
}, [info])
```

And delete this line

```
{info ? chunkEpisode() : console.log("")}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the response and setting info call chunkEpisode() with the data,rather than calling it from the return.

```
const getInfo = async () => {
    const { data } = await instance.get("/getInfo?slug=" + slug)
    setInfo(data.data)
    chunkEpisode(data.data)
    setDone(true)
}
```

Comment: Please make your sentence a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem lays in the `info.episodes.splice(0, 10)` .
Splice mutates the info state and triggers consecutive re-renders.

If you do it like this you'll see the error is gone and `episodeList` state is updated.

So depends on what you intended with slice you can go from here and modify the code below:

```
function MovieWatch({ instance }) {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
  const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
  const [episodeList, setEpisodeList] = useState([])

  let { slug } = useParams()

  const getInfo = async () => {
      const { data } = await instance.get("/getInfo?slug=" + slug)
      setInfo(data.data)
      setDone(true)
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    getInfo();
  }, [])

  const chunkEpisode = () => {
      const episodeListChunk = []
      // while (info.episodes.length) {
      //     episodeListChunk.push(info.episodes.splice(0, 10))
      // }
      info.episodes.forEach((e)=>{
        episodeListChunk.push(e)
      })
      console.log(episodeListChunk);
      setEpisodeList(episodeListChunk)
  }

  return (
      <>
          <div>Hello info page</div>
          {!done ? (
              <Loading loading={true} background="#000000" loaderColor="#FFFF00" />
          ) : (
              <>
                  {/* {info ? chunkEpisode() : console.log("")} */}
                  {episodeList.length ? episodeList : (chunkEpisode(), console.log(""))}
                  <div>Done loading</div>
              </>
          )}
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: If I do this then it'll return to the same root problem, I get `Too many re-renders`

Comment: Thanks, @MWO, this one indeed clear all the `error`, but is there anyways I can use the `episodeList` state? If I `console.log(episodeList)` it just return an empty `[]` array

Comment: I've answered it myself, too, but thanks, I'll try your code, thanks for helping me solving the problem